# Plot a bounding box around a sf object using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I would like to plot a world map (`sf` object) with a bounding box around the map. The bounding box would is supposed to represent the limits of the globe.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)

countries <- ne_countries(returnclass = "sf")
countries <- st_transform(countries, crs = "+proj=robin")

ggplot(countries) +
  geom_sf() +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could make your own `sf` polygon and plot that in its own layer:

```r
bound <- st_sf(geometry = st_sfc(
  st_polygon(x = list(cbind(c(-180, rep(180, 100), rep(-180, 100)),
                            c(-90, seq(-90, 90, length = 100), 
                              seq(90, -90, length = 100))))),
                      crs = 'WGS84'))

ggplot(countries) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data = bound, fill = NA, linewidth = 1.5, color = 'black') +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]